# Managing script block/command output for web pages in Java

Tags: java, jsp, scriptmanager, server-side-includes, script-tag

I've been looking around StackOverflow and doing broader searches to find some information about managing the output of JavaScript commands in a JSP page.  I'm not a Java developer so I'm asking for some guidance from the experts here.

I'm not trying to compile JavaScript on the server, but rather have a way to store code blocks or simple one-line commands for output within a JSP page.  The main goal is to decrease the use of multiple inline SCRIPT tags within a page by combining all the necessary commands and code blocks into one SCRIPT tag at the bottom of the page.  The code blocks and commands are typically used to initialize various components within a web page and some will include data from the server that is serialized to JSON and passed directly to a command or used to set values in tokenized strings that become script blocks and/or commands.

This object would need to be available to any JSP page and any server-side-included module/page.

I found questions like this one: [Where is the Java scripting engine used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016128/where-is-java-scripting-engine-used), but I don't want to compile script on the server, I want to output script for use within a web page.  I am a .Net developer and I'm familiar with the ScriptManager object which is used to do this exact task for built-in AJAX functionality on .Net web sites.  On another project I extended the .Net ScriptManager to do this.

Thoughts or suggestions are very much appreciated.

UPDATE:
Take for example the JSP code below.  I want to have an object in Java to store these the commands inside the  tags for output at the end of the page.

This is what I have now:

```
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="somelibrarycode.js"></script>
...
</head>
<body>
...
<%
    // server-side code to set a value:
    //   obj is an object with method getBar that returns string
    string foo = obj.getBar(); 
%>
<div id="someComponent"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // client-side code to initialize some page components:
    //    this would be what I consider a JavaScript command:
    someLibraryCode.someComponent.init('<%=foo%>');
</script>
...
...
...
...
<%
    // server-side code that to create instance of someObjectClass that has a  
    //   toJSON serializer method;
    someObjectClass myObject = new someObjectClass();
%>
<div id="anotherComponent"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // more client-side code that takes the result of myObject.toJSON() which is 
    //   a JSON encoded-string value:
    someLibraryCoode.anotherComponent.init(JSON.decode('<%= myObject.toJSON() %>'));
</script>
...
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I want to do:

(assume myScript.add() accepts a string and array as args)

```
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="somelibrarycode.js"></script>
...
</head>
<body>
...
<%
    // server-side code to set a value:
    //   obj is an object with method getBar that returns string
    string foo = obj.getBar();

    ScriptManager myScript = new ScriptManager();
    string commandString = "someLibraryCode.someComponent.init('{0}');";
    myScript.add(commandString, [foo]);
%>
<div id="someComponent"></div>
...
...
...
...
<%
    // server-side code that to create instance of someObjectClass that has a  
    //   toJSON serializer method;
    someObjectClass myObject = new someObjectClass();
    string myObjectJSON = myObject.toJSON();
    commandString = "someLibraryCoode.anotherComponent.init(JSON.decode('{0}'));";
    myScript.add(commandString, [myObjectJSON]);
%>
<div id="anotherComponent"></div>
...
...
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    // only one script tag within the body element
    // writeScript() outputs all stored script blocks/commands:
    myScript.writeScript();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will need to provide more details about how these scripts are written to the page.

Comment: I added a before and after example...

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is loaded and run on the client side, so this has nothing to do with Java or JSP and would be equally valid for any other web technology, including static html.
I would recommend to load a .js file at the end of the page:

```
...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and do whatever is needed in that script. It would typically place an onload handler on the window to do some initializations.
The script could also dynamically load more scripts if needed.

Comment: also, external scripts will be involved, but there are times when it's necessary to add various javascript blocks to do certain tasks when the page loads